# Gap between UL and DIV

Tags: jquery, html

JS slides my html vertically and when I'm in last image, there is a gap between the last element and a slider. It disappears when I delete "header".

This is my script

```
<body onload="
var div = $('#slider-left'),
    wrapScreenHeight = div.height(),
    wrapHeight = div.outerHeight(),
    listHeight = div.find('ul').outerHeight();
    topHeight = $('#slider-left ul').css('top');

div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageY,
        dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
          div.scrollTop((listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight);

});">
```

anyone know how to delete this gap without deleting this on top?

screens:

```
http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y455/gonliSs/gap_zpse2cb1f65.jpg
http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y455/gonliSs/gap2_zps828b716d.jpg
http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y455/gonliSs/gap3_zpse0ae33e7.jpg
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery please go ahead and move that horrible line from your onload into a proper script onload tag! ;)

Comment: A sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be more useful